# Inequality problem for sum of reals

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I am trying to solve this problem which is part of my home assignment. If the reals $z_{1},z_{2},\dots,z_{n}$ satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}=n$ and $z_{i}\geq-1$, then prove that they satisfy the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^{2021}\geq n$.

I think I need to use rearrangement inequality here but I am not able to think how to. AM-GM inequality will not be useful because of the condition $z_{i}\geq-1$. Any hints would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What actually is $z_i$ and what does the index $i$ represent?

Comment: $z_{i}$ are real numbers. I have updated the question.

Comment: Why must $z_i\ge-1$?

Comment: Its part of the problem, I thought of using AM-GM inequality but can't because of this condition.

Comment: Where does the problem come from? (The occurrence of “2021” might raise the suspicion that this is from an  active math contest.)

Comment: Its not. Its part of my homework problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be the  number of values of $z_i,1\le i \le n~~$ which are positive and let $q$ be the number of values of $z_i,1\le i \le n~~$ which are non-positive   . Let $a_i,1\le i \le p~~$  take all possible positive value of $z_i,1\le i \le n~~$ and let $b_i,1\le i \le q~~$  take all possible non-positive value of $z_i$
If $\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_{i}^{}=-r$ then $\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}^{}=n+r$ ($r$ is non-negative)

We can prove by induction $\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}^{k}\geq n+r$ where $k$ is a integer.
For $k=1$ it is true (equality holds here).
Now assume its is true for $k=m-1$, then by chebyshev's inequality

$$\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}^{m}\geq \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}^{m-1})(\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i})}{p}\ge \frac{(n+r)^2}{p}\ge \frac{(n+r)^2}{n}\ge n+r$$
We proved the inequality to be true for $k=m$ when we assumed it to be true for $k=m-1$, there by induction $\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}^{k}\geq n+r$ where $k$ is a integer.

$\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_{i}^{k}\geq -r$ because $|b_i|\le1$.
$$⇒ \sum_{i=1}^{n}z_{i}^{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{p}a_{i}^{k}+\sum_{i=1}^{q}b_{i}^{k}\geq n+r -r\ge n$$
It is easy to prove that equality holds only when $z_i=1,1\le i \le n~~$.

Comment: The prove by induction part could be done directly with power-mean, via a similar flavor.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Use  the tangent line approach:
Draw the tangent to $ y = x^{2021}$ at the point $ x = 1$, which is $ y = 2021x - 2020$.
Then ensure the graph is above the line for our desired domain, and find where equality holds.

**Lemma:** On $ [ -1, \infty ) $, we have $ x^{2021} \geq 2021x - 2020$.

> Consider $f(x) = x^{2021} - 2021 x + 2020$
>  Using Descarte Rule of Signs, $f(x) = 0$ has at most how many positive real roots?
>  Show that $x = 1$ is a double root, hence this is all of them.
>
>  Using Descarte Rule of Signs, $f(x) = 0$ has at most how many negative real roots?
>  Show that $f(-1) > 0, f(-2) < 0$, so it has exactly 1 negative root, which is in $(-2, -1)$.
>  Hence, the result follows.
>
>  Equality holds iff $x = 1$.

**Corollary:** $\sum x_i^{2021} \geq \sum ( 2021x_i - 2020 )  = 2021n - 2020n = n$. Equality holds iff $ x_i = 1$.

Comment: I really like this answer!

Comment: Calvin: have you read the meta post earlier this month: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1.  This site now holds also the answerers of very poor quality problem statements accountable for answering such poor questions, when you should instead suggest ways, first, for the asker to improve their post, and also search for duplicates.... i.e., all long before answering.

Comment: @amWhy No I have not. Noted, thanks.